# Are there any generalization of the lexical hypothesis that are being studied in philosophy?

Tags: epistemology, philosophy-of-science, metaphysics

The lexical hypothesis according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_hypothesis) is related to the following two postulates:

> The first states that those personality characteristics that are
> important to a group of people will eventually become a part of that
> group's language[6]. The second follows from the first, stating that
> more important personality characteristics are more likely to be
> encoded into language as a single word

I was wondering if the following generalizations of that hypothesis are known in the philosophical literature:

Any behaviour/procedure that is important in a group is very likely to be eventually encoded into the language of that group. It is also likely to be encoded in concise phrases or single words.
The rate of which this happens is depended(among others) to the concepts that are initially connected/grouped with the behaviour.

Comment: Well, we have a few real-life examples. One is a legend, but mostly true, about Inuits [having 50 words for distinct kinds of snow](https://readable.com/blog/do-inuits-really-have-50-words-for-snow/). The other one is Greek' 5 or 6 words for love, which, BTW, makes it possible to distinguish the problematic kind -- *Eros*, or romantic "have you pray'd to-night" love (Romeo & Juliette too, for its sheer body count) -- from the awesome *Agape*, which is similar to *compassion* because both are *understanding* before anything else. And yes, that distinction would be just as useful in English.

Comment: ... which makes one wonder, of course. On the other hand, there are a few of them *really* important words, like *lógos* or *ubuntu* that are notoriously hard to translate because modern languages don't have the words for the concepts they denoted (and we can't understand it unless we have a word for it).

Comment: And while we're on it, let's not forget peculiar incidents with modern words getting novel interpretations -- like, *__imitation__*, which, after having been *__the sincerest form of flattery__* since forever, one day became "a cultural appropriation". Unless blackface -- then its racist, and God have mercy on you and your moonwalk too.

Comment: Other times it's a sloppy (but very precise) choice of words. Like when oppression, which is a systematic infringement of human rights, gets described simply as unequal treatment. The latter, of course, can be addressed by *treating __everyone__ equally __bad__*. And let's face it -- inviting those *not* yet oppressed, whose rights are *still* respected to kindly check in their "privilege"... that's a neat move, for starters.

Comment: "__*The beginning of wisdom is the definition of terms*__" -- someone (metaphorically speaking), sure took Socrates' words to their heart (again, a metaphor).